# Selenium + Java - Footer blocking visibility of lowest element on page (the one I need)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Goal: Scroll all the way down a page and click an Edit clickableTextElement.

Using scrollTo(*[h2 of a table element]*) I'm going most of the way down the page but stopping at the h2. There are other selectors lower in the DOM/ under that h2 that I can't reach/ scrollTo either.

I've tried:

- window.scrollBy(x,y)
- WebDriverWait
- gradually scrolling down the page to elements on the way.

I've got it to work using a SECONDS.sleep(1) but my boss doesn't want that. Only thing that has worked.

Comment: Please share your code including a link to the page you are working on so we will be able to debug

Comment: It's a work page so not public and can't give it out.